# Multiple values when using IF function in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets

I have a list of points that need to be assigned in to a certain tier. For example:

<1250 = Tier 1 
1250-1650 = Tier 2

>1650 = Tier 3

I've been trying to use this formula:

```
=IF(AND(B2 > 0,B2 < 1250),"1",IF(AND(B2 > 1250,B2 < 1650),"2",IF(AND(B2 > 1650,B2 < 2000),"3")))
```

The problem is that when a value is 1250 "FALSE" is returned, I can't seem to figure out how to fix this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `= "Tier " & LookUp(B2, {0,1250,1651; 1,2,3})`

Answer (score 1):

`=IF(B2<1250,"1",IF(AND(B2>=1250,B2<=1650),"2",IF(B2>1650,"3")))`

Note that this will also populate cells with `1` if there's no number in the corresponding B cell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some equal signs to your inner and statement `(AND(B8 >= 1250,B8 <= 1650)`

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that you could also use this.

```
=IF(B2<1250,"1",IF(B2<=1650,"2","3"))
```